# If $T\in \mathcal{L}(\mathcal{H})$ is compact, then is $\{ x\in S_{\mathcal{H}}\; |\; \| Tx\| =\| T\| \}$ nonempty?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $\mathcal{H}$ is a Hilbert space. If $T\in \mathcal{L}(\mathcal{H})$ is compact, then is  $\{ x\in S_{\mathcal{H}}\; |\; \| Tx\| =\| T\| \}$  nonempty? where $S_{\mathcal{H}}$ denotes the unit sphere.

Comment: In fact, if $X$ is a Banach space, then $X$ is reflexive iff every compact operator on $X$ attains it's norm.

Comment: @EvangelopoulosF. Thank you very much for your comment. Could you give me a reference for this fact?

Comment: @M.Ramana The one direction is proven in Rurifangtun's answer. For the converse, you are going to need [James theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James%27s_theorem): try to prove that every element of $X^*$ attains its norm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is definitely yes.

Suppose that $\{x_n\}\subset S_{\mathcal H}$ is a sequence satisfying $$\|Tx_n\|\to\|T\|\quad\hbox{as $n\to\infty.$}$$ We note that $\mathcal H$ is a Hilbert space, so it must be reflexive. Thus, there exists a subsequence of $\{x_n\},$ which is still denoted by $\{x_n\}$, such that $\{x_n\}$ converges to $x_0$ weakly in $\mathcal H$. We note that $\|x_0\|\leq1.$ Since $T:\mathcal H\to\mathcal H$ is compact, we get $$Tx_n\to Tx_0\quad\hbox{as $n\to\infty$}.$$ Thus, $\|Tx_0\|=\|T\|$, and so $x_0\in S_{\mathcal H}$, which completes the proof.

Comment: In a reflexive Banach space, any bounded sequence must have a weakly convergent subsequence.

Comment: Thank you so much for your great answer. I have just one question: Why do you suppose that $\{ x_n \}\subset S_\mathcal{H}$ satisfying $\| Tx_n \| \to \| T\|$?

Comment: Since $\|T\|=\sup_{\|x\|=1}Tx,$ by the definition of superemum, we then obtain the existence of such a sequence $\{x_n\}$.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am so sorry. Why if $\{ x_n \}$ converges to $x_0$ weakly in $\mathcal{H}$ and $T$ is compact, we have $Tx_n \to Tx_0$?

Comment: @Rurifantun Could you please give an example of a noncompact operator $T$ for which $\{ x\in S_{\mathcal{H}}\; |\; \| Tx\| =\| T\| \}$ is empty?

Answer (score 4):

The operator $T^*T$ is compact and self-adjoint. The number $\|T^*T\|=\|T\|^2$ is its largest eigenvalue.  Let $v,$$\|v\|=1$ be a corresponding eigenvector. Then $$\langle T^*Tv,v\rangle =\|T\|^2.$$ Hence $\|Tv\|=\|T\|.$